# Get response data from phoenix socket push with saga generators

Tags: sockets, redux-saga

I'm using redux-saga with phoenix.js sockets and want to get response data after my push.

```js
export function* make({ channel }, action) {
  try {
    const q = yield apply(channel, channel.push, ["create", action.payload, 10000]);
  } catch() {
  }
}
```

I also see `receivedResp` key in `q` obj:
console.log(Object.keys(q));
// ["channel", "event", "payload", "receivedResp", "timeout", "timeoutTimer", "recHooks", "sent", "ref", "refEvent"]

But can't access the data like `q.receivedResp.response.data'. But console.log({ q }) shows me some.

What is actual `q` itself in this case and how to get response data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out by promisify push

```js
export const promisifyPush = (channel, ...args) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      channel.push(...args)
        .receive("ok", function (data) {
            console.log({ data  })
            resolve(data);
        })
        .receive("error", function (reasons) {
            reject({ channel: channel.topic, reasons })
        })
        .receive("timeout", function (error) {
            reject(error)
        });
    });
  };
```